# How to translate views footer content?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I am building a multilingual site using Drupal 7. I have used Views to generate a page, and in that page I have added a link in the view footer. The custom code that I use in my views footer is as below.

```
<?php <a href ="/blog-archieve">To blog archive</a>
```

My problem is that I am using i18n module to translate the contents. In the translate interface I get the full above code, and as a result I lose my footer in views. Is there any way by which I can translate the "To blog archive" instead of the full code?

Comment: can't see your code, can you pastebin it somewhere. try putting "To blog archive" in the t() function and then have a translation for the string "To blog archive", since it passes through t() it will be translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your footer to the following:

```
<?php
$link = l(t('To blog archive'), 'blog-archive');

print $link;
?>
```

References:

[`l();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7)

[`t();`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)

Comment: I think `'/blog-archive'` should probably be `'blog-archive'`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when i use this code in the footer region of my views, I get the code printed in the views page, not the "To blog archive".

Comment: @Slasengger you need to enable php.module and use the php filter in the Views footer.

Comment: ^this - I assumed you had it enabled already as you had an opening `<php` in your footer text.

Comment: Thanks a lot chapabu and andy:):) U both got me on the right track:):) the above code worked by enabling the php filter module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using the php filter and are ok with having the different translations all together, then you can use [Language Sections](http://drupal.org/project/language_sections). It uses a format like this:

> === es ===
>
> This text will only be displayed when Spanish language is selected by the user.
>
> === fr ===
>
> This text will only be displayed when French language is selected by the user.
>
> === others ===
>
> This part will be displayed when the user's selected language is neither Spanish nor French, i.e. all other languages, and so might provide text in a common language such as English.
>
> === all ===
>
> This part will be displayed for all languages.

You can also use [Internationalization Views](http://drupal.org/project/i18nviews). It doesn't have a stable release for 7.x, but it does have over 4k sites reporting they're using the 7.x dev release.

(I'm afraid I have no personal experience with either.)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply andy. The above 2 options did not provide a solution:(

Comment: @Slasengger sorry to hear that :/ Can you be more specific as to the problems?

Comment: Chapabu's code solved the issue. Thanks for reminding me to enable the php filter:)